# php explode doesn't second item

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'm trying to split this image string: `$output = "<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://asite.dev/sites/default/files/video/MBI_Part%201_v9.jpg" width="1920" height="1080" alt="" />`

I'm doing it like this: `$split = explode('"', $output);`

But when I `print_r($split);`it returns:

```
 Array ( [0] =>  typeof="foaf:Image" [2] => src="http://makingitcount.dev/sites/default/files/video/MBI_Part%201_v9.jpg" [3] => width="1920" [4] => height="1080" [5] => alt="" [6] => /> )
```

No second value! Where'd it go? `split[1]` throws an error, of course. I also notice that the "`<img`" part of the string isn't in the array either.

Comment: [use error reporting and you'll see the syntax error you're making](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) - `$output = "<img typeof="foaf:Image" <=` double quotes inside a double quoted statement.

Comment: You should escape double quotes inside the statement with \ or use single quotes inside it double quotes ' " " ' or " \" \" "

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the parsing of the html tag. If you remove the `<img` at the beginning of the html string, you'll notice the rest of the attributes will parse into an array with a proper number sequence (including a '1' element). You can solve your problem by formatting your quotes to tell php not to parse the html and treat the entire unit strictly as a string.

If you want to bypass this whole mess, you can also just use regular expression matching to collect tag information and pass it into an array. $matches[0][*] will contain all of your tag attributes, and $matches[1] contains the tag itself (img)

```
$output = '<img typeof="Image" src="http://asite.dev/sites/default/files/video/MBI_Part%201_v9.jpg" width="1920" height="1080" alt="" />';

$pattern = '( \w+|".*?")';
preg_match_all($pattern, $output, $matches);
preg_match("[\w+]",$output,$matches[1]);
print_r($matches);
```

which gives you

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => typeof [1] => "Image" [2] => src [3] => "http://asite.dev/sites/default/files/video/MBI_Part%201_v9.jpg" [4] => width [5] => "1920" [6] => height [7] => "1080" [8] => alt [9] => "" ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => img ) )
```